# What is the ajax life cycle in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

what is the life cycle of Ajax in 3.5? i mean to ask that how Ajax works in VS2008 ?

Comment: Same as it is without AJAX and async postbacks. An async postback  still reloads the entire page, but only what's in the UpdatePanel will be updated.

Comment: @Sergey: so you mean to say that there is no life cycle of ajax. If some one asked this then what should be answer, i think according to you we should say that there is no as such a particular life cycle of ajax but ajax enable page's life cycle is exacltly the same without ajax, am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client browser sends an asynchronous HTTP request to the server and the server would process this request as any other normal HTTP request. The only difference to the client is that during the processing of this request the browser doesn't freeze and the user doesn't need to wait for the request to finish and could perform some other tasks due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

From the perspective of the server there's **absolutely no difference**: incoming HTTP request, processing, returning a response.